# Transformer XL - understanding paper's illustration

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, transformer, attention-mechanism

If I understand correctly, the `Key` hidden layer in the Transformer XL is of size `2L * d`,  where `L` is the segment length and `d` is the embedding dimension.

> concatenation of two hidden sequences along the length dimension

Therefore, the size of the attention matrix would be `L X 2L`, where row `i` represents the attention `Query i` should apply to each of the `2L Keys`.

**That is, the self attention window length = 2 X segment length.**

However, in the following image from the paper, the segment length is 4 and there are only 4 lines linked to each node. Shouldn't there be 4 * 2 = 8 lines from each node?

[image]

[Link to transformer XL paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.02860.pdf)

Comment: Could you add the link to the paper?

Comment: Sure, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Github code, there is 2xNxD in the Multi head attention function indeed:

```
class MultiHeadAttn(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_head, d_model, d_head, dropout, dropatt=0, 
                 pre_lnorm=False):
        super(MultiHeadAttn, self).__init__()

        self.n_head = n_head
        self.d_model = d_model
        self.d_head = d_head
        self.dropout = dropout

        self.q_net = nn.Linear(d_model, n_head * d_head, bias=False)
        self.kv_net = nn.Linear(d_model, 2 * n_head * d_head, bias=False)

        self.drop = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.dropatt = nn.Dropout(dropatt)
        self.o_net = nn.Linear(n_head * d_head, d_model, bias=False)

        self.layer_norm = nn.LayerNorm(d_model)

        self.scale = 1 / (d_head ** 0.5)

        self.pre_lnorm = pre_lnorm
```

But kv refers to the key AND value vectors.

Source: https://github.com/kimiyoung/transformer-xl/blob/master/pytorch/mem_transformer.py

Comment: Yes I saw that, thanks.
Do you understand what the illustration is representing?

Comment: I don't know. Sometimes authors just simplify graphs because they want to explain concepts. I've already asked for explanations to many authors, and they generally answer.